# Reverted changes through bcdedit not recognized by bitlocker

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I used the following command in the console:
bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING ON

This made bitlocker ask for my recovery key on every boot, even after i changed it to the original value.

In the screen on boot it says "... 
Otherwise restore the original BCD setting".

Thats what i did. Why doesnt bitlocker recognize that i restored the original setting?

I know i can probably resolve this issue with the manage-bde command (suspend), but it is disabled through group policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no other way I went to the IT department. They suspended bitlocker through the manage-bde command and it was all fine after that.